# How to change the date time format for only SOME ROWS in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have a dataframe in which there are some columns. One of them is Date but some dates are in the format of dd-MMM-YY (eg: 03-May-2022) and some are in the format dd-mm-yy(eg: 03-05-2022). How do I change all the dates in the column to one format(eg: dd-mm-yy)?

**Initial Dataframe:**

| Serial | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 23-05-2022 |
| 1 | 14-Mar-2022 |
| 2 | 29-02-2020 |

**Required Output:**

| Serial | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 23-05-2022 |
| 1 | 14-03-2022 |
| 2 | 29-02-2020 |

Comment: Have you made any tries to solve the issue by yourself?

Comment: How do you get the df?  Did you try to solve the problem upper in the process? What is the requested type for the column?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of one solution where you handle the two different cases based on length of the date string:

```
def format_date(date):
    reformatter = {
        "Jan": "01",
        "Feb": "02",
        "Mar": "03",
        ...
        "Dec": "12"

    }
    if len(date) == 10:
        return date
    else:
        return date[:4] + reformatter[date[3:6]] + date[6:]

df["Date"].apply(lambda x: format_date(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use automatic date parsing:

```
df['Date'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], infer_datetime_format=True)
                .dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
              )
```

Or, using `str.replace`:

```
from calendar import month_abbr

d = dict(zip(month_abbr, [f'{i:02d}' for i in range(13)]))

df['Date'] = df['Date'].str.replace(r'[A-Z][a-z]+', lambda x: d.get(x.group(), x), regex=True)
```

Output:

```
   Serial        Date
0       0  23-05-2022
1       1  14-03-2022
2       2  29-02-2020
```

Comment: After reading Matt Harrison's Book, I'd use `df = df.assign(Date=lambda df_: pd.to_datetime(df_.Date), infer_datetime_format=True)` ;-)

Comment: @MichaelKopp that's pretty much the same thing. If you go through my contributions, you'll see I'm using `assign`+`lambda` all the time when in a pipeline. Not for a single expression ;)